# FileExistsError: [WinError 183] even with if not os.path.exists()

Tags: python

New to python and programming in general.

I am trying to create a directory if none exists by a certain name. The script works the first time through, creating a directory with my specified name. However when re-running the script, even with:

```
if not os.path.exists('name'):
    os.makedirs('name')
```

It returns FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'name'

Here is the full def:

```
def do_something(reload_something=False):

    if reload_something:
        things = save_something()
    else:
        with open("something.pickle","rb") as f:
            things = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('things_here'):
        os.makedirs('things_here')
```

Based on everything I have read about using if/not there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: try to give full path, `if not os.path.exists('\path\to\name'):`

Comment: Does it work with the full path? In windows it's often useful to use a raw string by adding an `r` to the front, e.g. `r'C:\some\dir`

Comment: Adding the full path solved the issue, as a new user I would appreciate any further explanation as to the difference between inserting the explicit path and what I tried. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @thelenf Your code, as pasted, worked for me fine on windows. So I think it must be something specific to your enivornment